# Как передать функцию контент скритпу из backgound.js?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, расширения

Я разрабатываю расширение для chrome, и когда я пытаюсь передать функцию контент скрипту из background.js, я получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.sayHi is not a function

Файл background.js:

```
function sayHi() {
  alert('hi')
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === "GET_CURRENT_TAB") {
    sendResponse({ sayHi: sayHi });
  }
});
```

Файл content-script.js:

```
(async () => {
  const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "GET_CURRENT_TAB",
  });

  response.sayHi();
})();
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что к вам приходит строка, а не фукнция, точнее текст фукнции, но это строка.

Comment: Приходит undefined, почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background.js:

```
let port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "my-channel" });

function sayHi() {
  alert('hi');
}

port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
  if (msg.action === "GET_CURRENT_TAB") {
    port.postMessage({ sayHi });
  }
});
```

content-script.js:

```
let port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "my-channel" });

port.postMessage({ action: "GET_CURRENT_TAB" });

port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
  msg.sayHi();
});
```

Есть ещё один способ - использовать `chrome.storage API`, для хранения и извлечения пары ключ-значение:

background.js

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'sayHi': sayHi}, function() {
  console.log('Function is set');
});
```

content-script.js

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['sayHi'], function(result) {
  let func = result.sayHi;
  func();
});
```